# Heap solution outperforming stack?

Tags: c++, c

I am coding a C simulation, in which, given a sequence of rules to verify, we break it up into 'slices' and verify each slice. (The basic idea is that the order is important, and the actual meaning of a rule is affected by some rules above it; we can make a 'slice' with each rule and only those rules above it which overlap it. We then verify the slices, which are usually much smaller than the whole sequence was.)

My problem is as follows.

I have a struct (policy) which contains an array of structs (rules), and an int (length). 
My original implementation used malloc and realloc liberally:

```
struct{
  struct rule *rules;
  int length;
}policy;
...
struct policy makePolicy(int length)
{
  struct policy newPolicy;
  newPolicy.rules = malloc(length * sizeof(struct rule));
  newPolicy.length = length;
  return newPolicy;
}
...
struct policy makeSlice(struct policy inPol, int rulePos)
{
  if(rulePos > inPol.length - 1){
    printf("Slice base outside policy \n");
    exit(1);
   }
  struct slice = makePolicy(inPol.length);
  //create slice, loop counter gets stored in sliceLength
  slice.rules = realloc(slice.rules, sliceLength * sizeof(struct rule));
  slice.length = sliceLength;
  return slice;
}
```

As this uses malloc'ed memory, I'm assuming it makes heavy use of heap.
Now I'm trying to port to an experimental parallel machine, which has no malloc.

I sadly went and allocated everything with fixed size arrays.

Now here's the shocker.

The new code runs slower. Much slower.

(The original code used to wait for minutes on end when the slice length was say 200, and maybe an hour at over 300 ... now it does that when the slice length is 70, 80 ... and has been taking hours for say 120. Still not 200.)

The only thing is that now the slices are given the same memory as a full policy (MAXBUFLEN is 10000), but the whole doesn't seem to be running out of memory at all. 'top' shows that the total memory consumed is quite modest, tens-of-megabytes range, as before. (And of course as I'm storing the length, I'm not looping over the whole thing, just the part with real rules.)

Could anyone please help explain why it suddenly got so much slower?

Comment: did you try using a profiler? Does it run slower on the new machine or on the same Machine?

Comment: Do you mean it now runs slower on the same machine? Or that it runs slower on your "experimental parallel" machine?

Comment: So far, this is on the same machine. I haven't run it on the parallel one yet. 
I should add, the verification is order pow(n,5) where n is the number of rules. So I think the time is taken in verification.
I'm trying to learn gprof right now, so I can profile and answer this better.

Comment: A simple (and effective) way to profile your code is just to grab stack traces from it at a few random intervals, either with gstack or gdb. You don't need more than a couple of samples to pinpoint the place where the majority of your execution time is being spent.

Comment: wait, so what are you doing now exactly? are you doing the following? or what?
struct{
  struct rule[MAXBUFLEN];
  int length;
}policy;

Comment: Why there's only one arg in your `realloc` call?

Comment: Fixed; bug because I wrote from memory. Thanks Naruil!
Yes matt, that is precisely what I am doing.
gprof shows, as best as I can see, that a substantial part of the time is in fact spent in projection (i.e. computing which rules overlap), and only a small part in probe. I am running more traces of both the dynamic and the static program to be sure. 
Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Ah, after some profiling I see that in the important cases - the ones which actually take some time to compute - most of the time is spent in resolve(), which takes the policy and a data point and returns the decision. 85-95% of time is spent here. This is understandable, because each data point probed has to be resolved.
(probe() is a distant second, at less than 10%.) 
These statistics seem to be true in both cases though.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when you fixed the size of the struct to a larger size (say 10000 rules), your cache locality could become much worse than the original one. You can use a profiler (oprofile or cachegrind in Valgrind) to see if cache is a problem.

In the original program, one cache line can hold at most 8 `struct policy` (on a 32bit machine with 64byte cache line).  But in the modified verison it can only hold one since it is now much larger than the cache line size.

Move the `length` field up can improve performance in this case since now the `length` and the first few `struct rule`s can fit into a single cache line.

```
struct policy{
  int length;
  struct rule rules[10000];
};
```

To solve this problem you need to write your own custom allocator to ensure cache locality. If you are writing a parallel version of this program, also remember to isolate memory used by different threads into different cache lines to avoid cache line contention.

Comment: Thank you for your field-moving idea, but I'm afraid it hasn't made much difference so far. I have implemented the order switch, but a slice with, say 50-75 rules, which flashes by in the old version, still stays onscreen for minutes now. 
I will try looking at Valgrind, but I would much appreciate some pointers to how I can write my own allocator - and also how I can isolate memory per thread!

Comment: @user2431187 It seems that there's a performance difference beyond what cache problem may cause. Have you made other changes to your program other than the data structure?

Comment: The only other change to the code is that I also used fixed length arrays to hold the test data points, in the probe() function. (This is quite a large array, but still not more than a megabyte or so.)
As a test, I have gone back and edited the code again, using malloc() for the array of data points. In my tests, this code runs faster than the code with only static arrays, but not nearly as fast as the code which malloc()s throughout. (Say an example with the largest slice being of length 130, is taking more than half an hour, vs minutes for the dynamic code, and overnight for the all-static.)

Comment: @user2431187 Are you writing a parallel program? If so, you must use thread local arrays instead of a global array to avoid false-sharing.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to get a parallel program, but so far I haven't converted it yet. In fact, the first hurdle is that rand(), time() and malloc() are not available on the new machine. I am going to write my own rand() and pass in a seed from the command line instead of time(), but I also want to figure out why moving away from malloc() made it so slow :) 
And there's no global array, probe() is a function - called only once per thread - that takes as input a policy, generates an array of test points, and tests the policy with these points. The array is local to probe(), not shared.